# How to order by in DynamoDB with the AWS SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-dynamodb

Currently, my range value is a BigDecimal attained by `Time.now.to_f`, and I want to retrieve all the documents of a user, like so:

```
table = dynamo_db.tables['some_table']
table.load_schema
docs = table.items.where(:user_id => user_id).select.map {|i| i.attributes}
```

The `docs` is ordered in the range value **descending**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the SDK source code, I was able to find this little useful nugget for the method AWS::DynamoDB::ItemCollection#query

```
  # @option [Boolean] :scan_index_forward (true) Specifies which
  #   order records will be returned.  Defaults to returning them
  #   in ascending range key order.  Pass false to reverse this.
```

Since my `user_id` is the hash value, I was able to revise my query to:

```
docs = table.items.query(:hash_value => user_id, :scan_index_forward => false).select.map {|i| i.attributes}
```

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't show up in the actual Ruby SDK documentation does it?

Comment: Not at all. From here on out I'm just going to read the source instead of looking at the documentation site.